# Is it possiable to encapsulate a splicing syntax into syntax-class?

Tags: macros, racket

For example, the following program

```lisp
(begin-for-syntax
  (define-splicing-syntax-class bindings
    (pattern (b*:bind ...)))

  (define-syntax-class bind
    #:datum-literals (:)
    (pattern (name:id : ty))))

(define-syntax-parser def
  [(_ name:id b*:bind ...)
   #''ok])

(def a [a : Num] [b : Num])

(define-syntax-parser def2
  [(_ name:id b*:bindings)
   #''ok])

(def2 a [a : Num] [b : Num])
```

`def` works as expected, but `def2` have to change to:

```lisp
(def2 a ([a : Num] [b : Num]))
```

I want to use `bindings` but still get `def` like form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `~seq` in the definition of `bindings`:

```
(define-splicing-syntax-class bindings
    (pattern (~seq b*:bind ...)))
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think like that, I always think `~seq a` is equal to `a ...`